# How to perform some action from my App when the user opens some other application in his device + Android

Tags: android

Basically I want to do the below through my App,

1. Identify user has opened an application in his device
2. Get the opened application meta data like name,version etc.,
3. Perform some action based on the application he opened

How to perform above steps?

Thanks,
poddroid

Answer (score 0):

There are no supported broadcasts to provide you your item #1, for security and privacy reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From your answer I understand that we cannot identify what application user has choosen. Fine. For my problem as a work around can I rely (I mean does I receive a unique running application Id) on the currently running application information?